# IPython how to print last n commands?

Tags: ipython

I am using IPython 2.7. I wish to print last 3 or 5 or in general 'n' commands. The `%hist` command prints all the commands till now. Note, here, by 'n' I do not refer to line numberings (i.e. IPython's indexing of each line).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get the last 5 commands:

```
%hist -l 5
```

You can see all the arguments that `%hist` supports by typing `%history?`.